# "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str": yaml.load_all?

Tags: python, yaml

I want to parse the YAML file having the following data structure:

```
    Version: 1
    TxnCode: MPT
    MessageID: "FFH-18544-1388620740-795905"
    Recommendations: 
     - {ReqSegFlightRef: [[1,2]],TotalPriceRef: 1,PriceInfoRef: 1}
     - {ReqSegFlightRef: [[3,4,2]],TotalPriceRef: 2,PriceInfoRef: 2}
     - {ReqSegFlightRef: [[5,4,2]],TotalPriceRef: 3,PriceInfoRef: 3}
    Flights: 
     - {OpCarrier: SN,MktCarrier: SN,FlightNb: 2902,DptDate: "0109",DptTime:     "09:30",ArrTime: "11:05",DptAirport: VIE,ArrAirport: BRU}
     - {OpCarrier: SN,MktCarrier: SN,FlightNb: 243,DptDate: "0109",DptTime: "12:15",ArrTime: "17:00",DptAirport: BRU,ArrAirport: FNA}
     - {OpCarrier: OS,MktCarrier: LH,FlightNb: 6325,DptDate: "0109",DptTime: "06:30",ArrTime: "07:35",DptAirport: VIE,ArrAirport: MUC}
    Prices: 
     - {TotalPrice: 1574.14,BaseAmount: 1368.00,TotalTaxe: 206.14,TotalSurcharge: 0.00,TotalFee: 0.00}
     - {TotalPrice: 1633.57,BaseAmount: 1368.00,TotalTaxe: 265.57,TotalSurcharge: 0.00,TotalFee: 0.00}
     - {TotalPrice: 1636.57,BaseAmount: 1368.00,TotalTaxe: 268.57,TotalSurcharge: 0.00,TotalFee: 0.00}
  LFSDetails: |
    PriceInfos: 
     - {FaresRef: [1,2],Price: {Total: 1574.14},Amount: {Total: 1368.00},Taxes:  {Total: 206.14},Surcharges: {Total: 0.00},Fees: {Total: 0.00}}
     - {FaresRef: [3,4,2],Price: {Total: 1633.57},Amount: {Total: 1368.00},Taxes: {Total: 265.57},Surcharges: {Total: 0.00},Fees: {Total: 0.00}}
     - {FaresRef: [3,4,2],Price: {Total: 1636.57},Amount: {Total: 1368.00},Taxes: {Total: 268.57},Surcharges: {Total: 0.00},Fees: {Total: 0.00}}
    ListCabinRequested: []
    FareInfo: 
     - {RBD: M,FareBasis: BFFOWAT,PTC: ADT,BreakPointId: N,Availability: 9,Cabin: W,FareType: OB}
     - {RBD: B,FareBasis: BFFOWAT,PTC: ADT,BreakPointId: Y,Availability: 9,Cabin: W,FareType: OB}
     - {RBD: B,FareBasis: BFFOWAT,PTC: ADT,BreakPointId: N,Availability: 9,Cabin: M,FareType: OB}
    Currency: EUR
```

I have the following code but I'm having a "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" in the line 20:

```
def yaml_load_all(iStream,iCodeFilter=None):
    for ayamldoc in yaml.load_all(iStream):
        lfsWrapper = LFSWrapper(iCodeFilter)
        lfsDetails = ayamldoc['LFSDetails'] #line 20
        if lfsDetails is not None:
            ayamldoc['LFSDetails'] = yaml.load(lfsDetails)
        lfsWrapper.loadDict(ayamldoc)
        if lfsWrapper.isValid():
            yield lfsWrapper
```

*(I'm calling this method later with iStream set to sys.stdin to read the data file).*

I think I'm missing something basic here regarding the data structure or the way the yaml.load_all is working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can provide the full Traceback, please. You can edit your question to add it.

Comment: Please read and follow the [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using PyYaml.

`load_all` is for loading multiple YAML documents in a single file, and so always returns a list. You just have a single document, which maps to a Python dict, so you should just use `load`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a strange if not an invalid YAML file, which makes it a bit of guess work what is going on here. The reason that it is a problematic YAML file is the

```
LFSDetails: |
```

line which has a different indentation (i.e. is outdented) compared to the lines before and after.

Up until `LFSDetails` the YAML file looks like it has a mapping at the top level. So the intial solution might be to just push `LFSDetails` in with two spaces to align it with that. That would result in an empty string as its literal block scalar (introduced with `|` and your code seems to rely on YAML as text block within YAML. So it looks like the indentation following all of the lines following `LFSDetails` is correct.

For your error message to appear your YAML file has to start with a dash (sequence indicator) indented 3 spaces:

```
   -
    Version: 1
  LFSDetails: |
    PriceInfos:
     - {FaresRef: [1,2],Price: {Total: 1574.14},Amount: {Total: 1368.00},Taxes:  {Total: 206.14},Surcharges: {Total: 0.00},Fees: {Total: 0.00}}
```

gives this error (I stripped out the irrelevant intermediate mapping entries). This however parses, but completely drops anything after the outdentation by `LFSDetails` ¹:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
   -
    Version: 1
  LFSDetails: |
    PriceInfos:
     - {FaresRef: [1,2],Price: {Total: 1574.14},Amount: {Total: 1368.00},Taxes:  {Total: 206.14},Surcharges: {Total: 0.00},Fees: {Total: 0.00}}
"""

for data in yaml.load_all(yaml_str):
    print(data)
    print data['LFSDetails']
```

gives you:

```
[{'Version': 1}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 54, in <module>
    print data['LFSDetails']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Because of the dash the mapping starting with `Version:` is the first element of a sequence/list and after that trying to access a list element with a string (`LFSDetails`) gets you the error.

You should therefore **first clean up your YAML to make it correct**. I also suggest to include the [start of document marker](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395) (`---`) even if you only have one document in the example file, since you are using `load_all()`. And get rid of the extra indentation (i.e. have things start in the first column of the line). After removing any spurious sequence starting dashes and get something like this:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
---
Version: 1
TxnCode: MPT
MessageID: "FFH-18544-1388620740-795905"
Recommendations:
 - {ReqSegFlightRef: [[1,2]],TotalPriceRef: 1,PriceInfoRef: 1}
 - {ReqSegFlightRef: [[3,4,2]],TotalPriceRef: 2,PriceInfoRef: 2}
 - {ReqSegFlightRef: [[5,4,2]],TotalPriceRef: 3,PriceInfoRef: 3}
Flights:
 - {OpCarrier: SN,MktCarrier: SN,FlightNb: 2902,DptDate: "0109",DptTime:     "09:30",ArrTime: "11:05",DptAirport: VIE,ArrAirport: BRU}
 - {OpCarrier: SN,MktCarrier: SN,FlightNb: 243,DptDate: "0109",DptTime: "12:15",ArrTime: "17:00",DptAirport: BRU,ArrAirport: FNA}
 - {OpCarrier: OS,MktCarrier: LH,FlightNb: 6325,DptDate: "0109",DptTime: "06:30",ArrTime: "07:35",DptAirport: VIE,ArrAirport: MUC}
Prices:
 - {TotalPrice: 1574.14,BaseAmount: 1368.00,TotalTaxe: 206.14,TotalSurcharge: 0.00,TotalFee: 0.00}
 - {TotalPrice: 1633.57,BaseAmount: 1368.00,TotalTaxe: 265.57,TotalSurcharge: 0.00,TotalFee: 0.00}
 - {TotalPrice: 1636.57,BaseAmount: 1368.00,TotalTaxe: 268.57,TotalSurcharge: 0.00,TotalFee: 0.00}
LFSDetails: |
  PriceInfos:
   - {FaresRef: [1,2],Price: {Total: 1574.14},Amount: {Total: 1368.00},Taxes:  {Total: 206.14},Surcharges: {Total: 0.00},Fees: {Total: 0.00}}
   - {FaresRef: [3,4,2],Price: {Total: 1633.57},Amount: {Total: 1368.00},Taxes: {Total: 265.57},Surcharges: {Total: 0.00},Fees: {Total: 0.00}}
   - {FaresRef: [3,4,2],Price: {Total: 1636.57},Amount: {Total: 1368.00},Taxes: {Total: 268.57},Surcharges: {Total: 0.00},Fees: {Total: 0.00}}
  ListCabinRequested: []
  FareInfo:
   - {RBD: M,FareBasis: BFFOWAT,PTC: ADT,BreakPointId: N,Availability: 9,Cabin: W,FareType: OB}
   - {RBD: B,FareBasis: BFFOWAT,PTC: ADT,BreakPointId: Y,Availability: 9,Cabin: W,FareType: OB}
   - {RBD: B,FareBasis: BFFOWAT,PTC: ADT,BreakPointId: N,Availability: 9,Cabin: M,FareType: OB}
  Currency: EUR
"""

for data in yaml.load_all(yaml_str):
    lfs_data =  data['LFSDetails']
    nested_data = yaml.load(lfs_data)
    print(type(nested_data))
    print(nested_data['FareInfo'][1]['BreakPointId'])
```

which gets you as output:

```
<type 'dict'>
Y
```

---

¹ <sub>This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) of which I am the author. It is an enhanced version of PyYAML and the results using that should be similar.</sub>